# Overcoming supination/pronation issues with ice skates

Tags: iceskating

When I wear ice skates I have a supination problem issue.
This means that my feet are slightly bent outside while I skate.

This causes imbalances, problems of stability, pain on longer rides.
Then to compensate it I have to bend my knees quite inward, and this it's not so healthy for my joints.

I solved my problem in inline skating buying a pair of skates that allow lateral adjustment and adding also shims/wedges between the boot and the frame.

Searching between the ice skating available on the market seems to me that there are no ice skates that allow lateral adjustment and the blade it's always fixed with the boot.

Do you have any advice about how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 5):

High quality ice skates are usually bought in two parts:  the boots and the blades.  The blades are put on the boots by either the seller of the skates or by a technician at a rink which has a substantial figure skating clientele.  Such an ensemble cost me several hundred dollars when I bought my last pair of ice skates 25 to 30 years ago.  (I think about $300.)  You try on the combination, and if it doesn't feel right, the technician will adjust the blade/boot interface until it does.  Source:  Myself, who has bought several pairs of skates this way.

Whether the seller or the technician can address your problem in this way, I do
not know.

**Addendum in response to comment by the OP:**  The skates I mentioned in my answer are expensive, and it makes sense that you are reluctant to gamble.  I agree that my answer is incomplete, with reference to your question.  About all I can say is that buying boots and blades separately from a pro shop where you can discuss your requirements with an actual person is the place to start, not end.  The pro-shop fitter may be able to suggest a solution than does not involve buying expensive skates. The ones I have known took pride in solving problems and making their skaters happy.  (But that was a long time ago.)

Comment: Do you mean that if boots and blades are separate in two parts are they always lateral adjustable?
I wasted hours checking on internet ice skates with lateral adjustment features and I didn't found any. In inline skating searching for lateral adjustable I can find some.
And this is how I pick the inline skates I use.
I don't want to risk buying an expensive pair of ice skates and waste my money because I can't adapt them to my feet.

Comment: Don't know if this is full-answer worthy or not, but I had the same issues you're having (yes, it was quite bad) but it was purely down to using badly fitting skates. So it's possible you might not need any adjustment

Answer (score 1):

Entry level beginner or recreation skates (skates with rivets) are not adjustable. Most skates above beginner with screws are adjustable. The blade is mounted to the boots with screws and they have temporary mount holes that allow the blades to be moved inward or outward laterally. For supination we move them to the outside by 5mm or however much is required to glide straight without catching an inside edge and the opposite for supination, the blade is moved to the inside so the skater doesn't catch an outside edge when trying to glide straight.

Look at the bottom of the mid-level skates you are planning to buy and if they have screws,  typically they can be adjusted. Generally, the boot also is leather on the base where the blade plate meets the outsole. This means if significant adjustment needs to be made to the skate blade location they can be plugged and remounted. It is always better to have someone who understands skating and how the boot and blade work on the ice mounting and adjusting the blade. If you wish to take this on yourself there will be a lot of study required past adjusting the temporary mount screws.

The Jackson skates starting at the Fusion series are all completely adjustable[ the step below (Ascend series) are technically adjustable but have PVC outsoles and plugging for full remounting is more complex.
With Rieddell, the skates are fully adjustable starting at the diamond and up in the competitive series

It is important to point out every skate brand uses different measuring and sizing. For example in women's a size 8c/d in Riedell typically fits a 9½-10 wide in women's USA street shoe depending on if you want a comfort or competitive fit. In Jackson the size would be a 9 or 9.5D. It is all based on their proprietary measurements. Edea,  we have found, for example, don't fit wide feet ever, and their sizing is in metric plus 1.5cm or 15mm. So always check the manufacturer's size chart for the specific model. Even some models size differently in the same company.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I bought two cheap ice blades on Ali Express for a few dollars, I removed the wheels from my Rollerblade RB80 PRO that have a laterally adjustable frame and added them.
I also added some wedges as shown in this video at minute 9:00
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRrkMGn8BT8&t=2s&ab_channel=pascalbriand

I also had to sharpen them in an ice hockey specialized shop because they came totally not sharpen.

So with around 20 Euros, I got my ice skates!